# How to retrieve values from current signed in User Firebase,Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not able to retrieve any of the values from my datasnapshot. I've tried several methods and techniques, but it's given a null value.

[image]

The image of my database is above. 
Please see my code below,trying to log a value, everything seems right but not working.

```
email = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
editTextfragmentF = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_firstname);
editTextfragmentL = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_lastname);

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String UserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference().child("Users").child(UserID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                email.setText(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

                //Gets current users first name
                String FN = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("firstName").getValue());
                Log.i("First Name", FN);

                /*String LN = dataSnapshot.child("lastName").getValue().toString();
                Log.i("Last Name", LN);*/
                /*editTextfragmentF.setText(FN);
                editTextfragmentF.requestFocus();*/

                /*editTextfragmentL.setText(LN);
                editTextfragmentL.requestFocus();*/
            }
        }
```

The Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

`database.getReference().child("Users").child(UserID).addChildEventListener`

with

```
    database.getReference().child("Users").child(UserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        email.setText(dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class));
        String FN = dataSnapshot.child("firstName").getValue(String.class);
        Log.i("First Name", FN);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

Make sure you have granted internet access in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !@Gastón Saillén. That worked all i needed to change was the interface used, as said to ValueEventListener and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

getValue() takes in type of object to be returned. In your case your are getting a string value so just pass String.class into the method then save it into a String variable.

```
String firstname=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
Log.i("First Name", firstname);
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help, appreciate @David Innocent. Yes the value to be returned is a string, so you could either convert the datasnapshot value gotten, to a string using String.Valueof() or the toString()  method as well or like you said pass the String.class into the method. But the issue was with the interface being used.